# Directive/scope inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Maybe this is sort of two questions in one.  I know you have to explicitly declare directives to be used inside a Component for Angular 2.  Does this propagate to children Components of the Component, and if not, can it be made to?  Second, do variables declared on the Component propagate to children, or do they have to be explicitly passed to the Component?

Comment: They plan on implementing what you mention. [See this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2844). However, it keeps getting pushed back, so you'll have to wait.

Comment: I guess this is a hard nut to crack because the idea of modularity dictates that a component/module does not have dependencies that are implicit.If you were to move your child component somewhere else, it would break. This is usually solved with inheritance or dependency injection, which creates a strong bond between the child and the parent component and in turn makes your child component impssible to move around on its own.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense in the same way as functional programming then...unfortunately it means I have some work to do ;)

Answer (score 2):

As of beta.14 you have to explicitly list all used directives in `@Component`'s `directives` array. For the second part of the question, variables declared on component (eg: `this.name`) are not propagated to child components. To achieve that you have to pass them explicitly in components template using attributes like `<child [item]="parentItem"></child>` and child component must contain `@Input item` property.

**EDIT**: 
To incorporate clarification from comment... It is possible to register directives globally but only in `bootstrap` function. Directives declared on parent will **NOT** be inherited by child component.

```
bootstrap(App, [
    PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES,
    provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [SomeDirective, SomeComponent], multi:true})
]);
```

Comment: You can make direcitves globally available with `provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [SomeDirective, SomeComponent], multi: true})`, same with pipes `bootstrap(App, [provide(PLATFORM_PIPES, {useValue: RainbowizePipe, multi:true})]);`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification